# Why is my 3D position inaccurate when using cv2.stereoRectify and cv2.reprojectImageTo3D?

Tags: opencv, 3d, point-clouds

I am using these calibration camera parameters: https://github.com/MasazI/DeepLearning_TensorFlow/blob/master/KITTI/data/2011_09_26/calib_cam_to_cam.txt to try to project the center of an object's bounding box to 3D via:

```
    K_02 = np.array(
        [
            [956.95, 0, 693.98],
            [0, 952.24, 238.61],
            [0, 0, 1],
        ]
    )
    K_03 = np.array([[901.1, 0, 698.29], [0, 897.06, 237.74], [0, 0, 1]])
    R_rect_02 = np.array(
        [
            [0.99987, 0.015128, -0.0057419],
            [-0.015129, 0.99989, -0.00012875],
            [0.0057392, 0.0002156, 0.99998],
        ]
    )
    T_02 = np.array([[0.059897], [-0.0013678], [0.0046376]])
    T_03 = np.array([[-0.47563], [0.0052966], [-0.0054372]])
    translation23 = T_03 - T_02
    dist_l = np.array([-0.3751, 0.20768, 0.00043485, 0.0016032, -0.074692])
    dist_r = np.array([-0.3686, 0.19087, -0.00056895, 0.00033323, -0.063029])
    imageSize_l = np.array([1224, 370])
    cvQ = np.zeros((4, 4))
    cv2.stereoRectify(
        cameraMatrix1=K_02,
        cameraMatrix2=K_03,
        distCoeffs1=dist_l,
        distCoeffs2=dist_r,
        imageSize=imageSize_l,
        R=R_rect_02,
        T=translation23,
        R1=None,
        R2=None,
        P1=None,
        P2=None,
        Q=cvQ,
    )
    cx = K_02[0, 2]
    cy = K_02[1, 2]
    fx = K_02[0, 0]
    fy = K_02[1, 1]
    cx_prime = instrinsics_r[0, 2]
    tx = t_value
# expected format of Q per https://answers.opencv.org/question/187734/derivation-for-perspective-transformation-matrix-q/
    Qexp = np.array(
        [
            [1, 0, 0, -cx],
            [0, 1, 0, -cy],
            [0, 0, 0, fx],
            [0, 0, -1 / tx, (cx - cx_prime) / tx],
        ],
    )

    pointcloud = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(
            disparity_map, cvQ, handleMissingValues=False
        )
        # visualize x,y as green target in image
    x, y = 255,443
    actual_position = pointcloud[x][y]
```

I run this on a rectified image and the results are:

expected 3D position in world frame:
-1.333895, 1.397117, 5.923950

actual 3D position in world frame:
-2.632, -0.012436, 7.9008

These units are in meters, so the error is quite big. I understand ground-truth might not be measuring the exact pixel as me, but I would expect the error to be less than 1 meter at least.

I then reproject my 3D point back to 2D which is the blue point in the image and you can see there is a big reprojection error since it is far from the original x,y point (shown in green):

[original pixels vs reprojected pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCs1E.jpg)
and my disparity map visualized:
[disparity map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITkSL.png)

Am I calling reprojectImageTo3D incorrectly or is this likely an issue with my disparity map instead? I create the disparity map with StereoSGBM_create and createDisparityWLSFilter.

And how do they calculate Q in reprojectImageTo3D? Because from this https://answers.opencv.org/question/187734/derivation-for-perspective-transformation-matrix-q/ I expect it to be close to (which also gives me accuracy issues):

```
[[          1           0           0     -693.98]
 [          0           1           0     -238.61]
 [          0           0           0      956.95]
 [          0           0     -1.8519     -7.9902]]
```

instead, it is:

```
 [[          1           0           0     -751.02]
 [          0           1           0     -256.46]
 [          0           0           0      924.65]
 [          0           0      1.8668          -0]]
```